# ERROR KeyProviderCache: Could not find uri with key

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

Below is the simple code to create HIVE table, and load data in it.

```
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
import sqlContext.implicits._

val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("HIVE_Test").setMaster("local").set("spark.executor.memory","1g").set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true");
val sc = new SparkContext(conf);
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc);

sqlContext.sql("CREATE TABLE test_amit_hive12(VND_ID INT,VND_NM STRING,VND_SHORT_NM STRING,VND_ADR_LN_1_TXT STRING,VND_ADR_LN_2_TXT STRING,VND_CITY_CD STRING,VND_ZIP_CD INT,LOAD_TS FLOAT,UPDT_TS FLOAT, PROMO_STTS_CD STRING, VND_STTS_CD STRING)");
sqlContext.sql("LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH 'path_to/amitesh/part.txt' INTO TABLE test_amit_hive12");
exit()
```

I have 2 queries::

1) In the "create table", I have hard coded the table names, but how would the code understand what delimiter the file is having ? when we create a HIVE table through HIVE prompt, we do write following lines

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘’
LINES TERMINATED BY ‘’
```

So, don't we need to do that while working with Spark/Scala?

2) While executing the code through Spark-shell, I am getting below error::

```
 ERROR KeyProviderCache: Could not find uri with key [dfs.encryption.key.provider.uri] to create a keyProvider !!
res1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [result: string]
```

I found a post on stackoverflow, but it was unanswered. On other website, i found that its a bug with Hadoop 2.7.1. I checked mine, I have 2.7.2. So, what is the possibilities of the bug existing with my version. I am using IBMs BigInsight. Following is my version details

```
Hadoop 2.7.2-IBM-12
```

However, is there any one who could help me resolve this issue, I will have to have a very strong proof to prove this as a bug to my Manager.

Below is one of link where people says  the error is a bug

`https://talendexpert.com/talend-spark-error/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit late, but does this solve your problem?

Got the same error, but it was not really a problem for me.
After the error the code ran just fine. Sometimes it pops up and sometimes it doesn't, so maybe it is connected to the executor nodes on our cluster that are involved in the particular Spark job.

It is not directly related to the Hadoop version, but it is based on the Spark version you run.

Bug and solution are reported here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-20594.

That is, upgrading to Spark 2.2.0 probably will solve this issue.