# ERROR KeyProviderCache: Could not find uri with key [dfs.encryption.key.provider.uri] to create a keyProvider

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, pyspark

I am getting error while inserting data into hive table but data is getting inserted successfully in table.

```
act = sqlContext.createDataFrame(df,schema)

act.createOrReplaceTempView("act_view")

sqlContext.sql("insert into table project_defect.biweb_t_activity select * from act_view")
```

Give me this following error:

> **KeyProviderCache: Could not find uri with key [dfs.encryption.key.provider.uri] to create a keyProvider**

I am using Hortonworks Platform, if any one has faced this issues please suggest.

Comment: @pheeleepoo instead of Edit letter from upper case to lower case and vice versa can you please provide answer for the above problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ERROR KeyProviderCache: Could not find uri with key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42831545/error-keyprovidercache-could-not-find-uri-with-key)

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42831545/error-keyprovidercache-could-not-find-uri-with-key Looks to be a bug on Spark which was fixed with 2.2.0 version.

Comment: @ Sivaprasanna Sethuraman i am using spark version 2.1.1.2.6.1.0-129.But still i am getting error , this job is working perfectly but at last i am getting this error due to that my scheduling job get effected.

Comment: Yeah.. you're using 2.1.1 (with HDP 2.6.1) but the bug was fixed in 2.2.0.

Comment: @Sivaprasanna Sethuraman requesting you to please give me an idea how to ignore/pypass this error due to this only schedule will fail